# INSERT TRIGGER IF EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, database-trigger

I have looked through many articles and questions on here regarding this type of trigger but can't seem to find the exact answer.

Hopefully its a very quick one, or me being silly...

I have this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[JobCategoriesInsertTrigger]
ON [dbo].[JobCategories]
FOR INSERT
AS
    IF EXISTS(SELECT [name], [areaId] FROM JobCategories WHERE [name] = (SELECT [name] FROM inserted) AND [areaId] = (SELECT [areaid] FROM inserted))
    BEGIN
      RAISERROR('THIS RECORD ALREADY EXISTS', 10, 1)
      PRINT 'The record you are trying to insert already exists'
      ROLLBACK
    END
```

I get the following when trying a non-existing insert:

```
THIS RECORD ALREADY EXISTS
The record you are trying to insert already exists
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

My question is, where have I gone wrong? - the name and areaid DO NOT, exist in the insert I am trying but I get stopped, have I done something a little backwards there?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is my Insert:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[JobCategories]
           ([id]
           ,[name]
           ,[description]
           ,[areaId]
           ,[enabled])
     VALUES
           (NEWID(),
           'test01',
           'testitem',
           '2C6F2293-2BBD-4E54-9709-FB9C4C0200F55',
           1)
GO
```

Example of data already in the table:

```
id                                     name    description      areaId
D120B34D-8074-4EA1-A52D-9477C3A9DFAF    500    STAT12 EXCEPTION 954A8859-311A-4F86-80CD-4E6DC4E5103E
4B737203-6E6D-435B-9BAD-95C3B28DCCB1    501    STATIC EXCEPTION 954A8859-311A-4F86-80CD-4E6DC4E5103E
A653FADC-996B-4E6F-80F4-5C08202228E2    551    EXCEPTION 70     954A8859-311A-4F86-80CD-4E6DC4E5103E
```

Comment: I think name and areaid already exists  and thats the cause for this error.please provide some sample data for us to test,so that we can repro the same issue you are facing..

Comment: Also what happens if there are mutiple values in insert ?? your exist may not work in that scenario

Comment: You wrote an AFTER INSERT TRIGGER. You are checking the existence of the record after it completes the insertion. Of course the record exists.

Comment: The data does not exist for what I am trying to insert, only these 2 columns need comparing with the way the software validates the data - Would a INSTEAD OF INSERT help?

Comment: Your main issue is the fact that you're assuming the trigger will only ever have **one row** in the `Inserted` pseudo table - that is **NOT** the case! If you insert 5 rows at once, `Inserted` contains those 5 rows - and then your selects `SELECT [name] FROM inserted` will select which of these five names, and which of these five areaIds?? This is never going to work. The trigger is fired **once per statement** - so you **must be prepared** to handle **multiple rows** inside `Inserted`

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to use triggers to guarantee distinct rows. You could achieve this by setting up a [unique constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints) over two columns of your table:

```
CREATE TABLE [JobCategories] 
(
     id INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
     name VARCHAR(10), 
     areaid INT
)

ALTER TABLE dbo.JobCategories
ADD CONSTRAINT uq_JobCategories UNIQUE(name, areaid);

INSERT INTO [JobCategories] (name, areaid) 
VALUES ('test1', 1), -- will work
       ('test1', 2) -- will also work

SELECT * FROM [JobCategories]
```

And now, try to insert something that already exists:

```
INSERT INTO [JobCategories] (name, areaid) 
VALUES ('test1', 1) -- will fail
```

Message:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 17
> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'uq_JobCategories'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.JobCategories'. The duplicate key value is (test1, 1). The statement has been terminated.

[This article by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers) is a very good read.

Comment: Thank you - I thought this would work at first but I have double checked with our software dev and they state things can share the same "areaId" but when inserting a new category they have to be checked that the name and areaid don't already exist..... Apologies for the lack of information I was only going off what I was given initially..

Answer (score 1):

The record already exists at the time the trigger-function is being executed.

You can use an [`INSTEAD OF`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)-Trigger to replace the standard action of the INSERT statement.

But there are better ways to ensure no duplicates are inserted.

(first of all [unique constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints), like already mentioned in @RigertaDemiri's answer.)